# double to string in c++

Tags: c++, string, double

I'm trying to convert the expression "5 + b * 18" to "5+16.89*18". My problem is inside the while loop. I managed to remove the spaces.

My code:

```
double number = 16.89;
size_t found;
ostringstream converted;
string str ("5 + b * 18");

str.erase(remove(str.begin(),str.end(),' '),str.end());

found = str.find_first_of (VALID_CHARS);

while (found != string::npos)
 {        
  converted << fixed << setprecision (8) << number;        
  str.insert(found, converted.str());                                               
  found = str.find_first_of (VALID_CHARS,found + 1);
 }
```

Can anyone help me?

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert()` will shift the contents of the string to the right after the inserted text, but does not delete the character at the given position.  You should use `replace()`, specifying a size of ` (to replace just a single character)

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework? If not, I'd really advice against doing this kind of parsing yourself. There are dedicated libraries for this kind of things which have been extensively tested, such as [muParser](http://muparser.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

Use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/). It's great for converting most primitive types into strings.

```
int main()
{
  double number = 16.89;
  char buffer [50];
  sprintf(buffer, "5 + %f * 18",number);
}
```

Comment: I did not give the downvote, but I suspect it's because `sprintf` requires you to do your own memory management, which is rather error-prone. For a nice and type-safe variant for this kind of problem, I would suggest `boost::lexical_cast` (assuming that the poster wants to use parts of the Boost libraries).

Comment: The only errors this is prone to is human error. I'll take "error-prone" if its more elegant and fast. I also agree about the Boost implementation. Needless to say, I don't think my response was "not useful" in any way.

Comment: You are right and I do not think this warranted a downvote either. Just wanted to offer a possible explanation.

Comment: I dont know how to use boost::lexical_cast

Comment: @tiggares It's easy: `std::string numberString = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(number)`, where `number` is your `double` variable from above. This would create a string that contains `16.89`. You would now have to insert this string at the proper position in your variable `str`.

Comment: I tried this, but the compiler is saying that i dont have boost/lexical_cast.hpp library. The problem about my code is that its doing right only in the first time.. if i have two "b" in the expression, the second "b" will have the 16.8916.89 value! Sorry about my english